# "filter_input" vs "INPUT_COOKIE" previous value of the cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

I have this:

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['someCookie']) && filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'someCookie') != '' ){
    $idX = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'someCookie');

    var_dump('cookie:' . $_COOKIE['someCookie']);
    var_dump('variable:' . $idX);
}
```

Before the execution of this script, the cookie updates its value with the identification of an operation in my database.

The first time I execute, "var_dump" shows something like this:

> cookie: 1
>
> variable: 1

Ok, but when I do another operation, generate a new id, load the page, and update the cookie, the second time I execute this shows:

> cookie: 2
>
> variable : 1

I can't understand this, is like "filter_input" is getting the old value of the cookie.

Comment: where are you setting the cookie?

Comment: In the index.php, before the first tag (<!DOCTYPE...).

Comment: So Im assuing that this script is actually working fine, and that when you open up id 1 the cookies  value is 1 and when you open up id 2 the cookies value is set to two, can you show me how you set the cookie

Comment: setcookie("someCookie", $databaseReturnedID);
$_COOKIE['someCookie'] = $databaseReturnedID;

Comment: Your not setting the cookie in this script as its already there you have to reload the page to get the update that happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the cookie on the on the page so your idx value is reading the value that was stored on the server when the page loads. You set the cookie in the same script, so you would need to reload the page to get the idx variable to show the same.